# google map get rid of marker

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving data from firebase with key "status". If status is true, I will show the marker. If it is false, the marker need to disappear from the map. Ive spent countless hours doing this which should work but I don't know what I'm missing. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
func ihelprLocationCoordinateMappers() {

    dbFir.child("frontEnd/users").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let receivePostSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("receivePost")

        for child in snapshot.children {

            let receivePostSnapshot = child.childSnapshotForPath("receivePost")
            let coordinates = receivePostSnapshot.childSnapshotForPath("userCoord").value as! [String: AnyObject]
            let lat = coordinates["lat"] as! Double
            let long = coordinates["long"] as! Double
            let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)

            let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)

            let status = receivePostSnapshot.value!["status"] as! Bool

            if status {
                // marker will be placed on the map
                marker.map = self.mapView

            } else {
                // if status equal false marker need to dissapear
                print("status will not show")

                // for somereason the maker is is not dissapearing
                if marker != nil {

                    marker.map = nil
                }

            }

        }

    })

}
```

[image: Json Tree]

Comment: Have you tried utilizing the .hidden property? (ex: marker.map.hidden = true)

Comment: that did not work app crash because it is say that marker is nil

Comment: can you post your JSON tree.

Comment: @Dravidian Please check out the edit I added the Json tree

Comment: Try printing the status ..are you receiving the status from firebase? and try debugging and check if call ever goes to `if` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Two things first :-

1.) Have you set the delegate of `mapView` in `viewDidLoad` , if not set `mapView.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad Function

2.) Try printing `status` and `position` and check if your recieved location and status matches to your database.

if above both are fine then try this :-

```
 let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

 if let status = receivePostSnapshot.Value!["status"] as! Bool{

        if status == true {
            let marker = GMSMarker(position: location)
            marker.map = self.mapView

        } else if (status == false && marker != nil){

                marker.map = nil

          }
        }else{

        if marker != nil {

                marker.map = nil
            }


  }
```